# Compatible SQL function for Excel FDist

Tags: excel, t-sql

Does anyone know that is there a compatible function in SQL for Excel FDIST and FINV? If there is no, anyone has any idea how to build that? May be in C#?

Thanks. Your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: should be tagged with `C#`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to resolve my problems by using a library from .Net Framework 4.0 and above (System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.StatisticFormula).

I am able to develop a function in C# using the above library for my calculation process. This is a powerful library where you can find mostly common use statistical formula in there (e.g. mean, median, t distribution, f distribution, and inverse of them.)

Below are the code snippet from me:

```
using System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting;

private Chart ch = new Chart(); // You will need to declare an object of Chart type, as Statistic Formula class does not have a public constructor
double fDist = ch.DataManipulator.Statistics.FDistribution(fRatioVariance, degreeFreedom1, degreeFreedom2);
```

Hope this will help others. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Though its too late but below are some statistical function implementation in SQL Server itself.

To get FDist function (equivalent to Excel - FDist), we will be needing Complete and Incomplete beta function as well as gamma function:

```
--GAMMA Function
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[udf_Gamma]
(
@x Float=NULL
)
RETURNS Float
AS
BEGIN

Declare @f Float = 10E99;
Declare @g Float = 1;
        if ( @x > 0 )
        Begin
            while (@x < 3)
            Begin
                SET @g = @g * @x;
                SET @x = @x + 1;
            End
            SET @f = (1 - (2/(7*power(@x,2))) * (1 - 2/(3*power(@x,2))))/(30*power(@x,2));
            SET @f = (1-@f)/(12*@x) + @x*(log(@x)-1);
            SET @f = (exp(@f)/@g)*power(2*PI()/@x,0.5);
        End
        else 
        Begin
            SET @f = 10E99
        End
return @f;

END

--BETA Complete Function
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[udf_BetaC]
(
@x Float=NULL
,@a Float=NULL
,@b Float=NULL
)
RETURNS Float
AS
BEGIN
--double betacf(double a,double b,double x){

Declare @maxIterations int = 50, @m int =1
Declare @eps Float = 3E-5
Declare @am Float = 1;
Declare @bm Float = 1;
Declare @az Float = 1;
Declare @qab Float = @a+@b;
Declare @qap Float = @a+1;
Declare @qam Float = @a-1;
Declare @bz Float = 1 - @qab*@x/@qap;
Declare @aold Float = 0;
Declare @em Float, @tem Float, @d Float, @ap Float, @bp Float, @app Float, @bpp Float;

while((@m<@maxIterations) AND (abs(@az-@aold)>=@eps*abs(@az)))
Begin
    SET @em = @m;
    SET @tem = @em+@em;
    SET @d = @em*(@b-@m)*@x/((@qam + @tem)*(@a+@tem));
    SET @ap = @az+@d*@am;
    SET @bp = @bz+@d*@bm;
    SET @d = -(@a+@em)*(@qab+@em)*@x/((@a+@tem)*(@qap+@tem));
    SET @app = @ap+@d*@az;
    SET @bpp = @bp+@d*@bz;
    SET @aold = @az;
    SET @am = @ap/@bpp;
    SET @bm = @bp/@bpp;
    SET @az = @app/@bpp;
    SET @bz = 1;
    SET @m = @m + 1;
End

return @az

END

--BETA INCOMPLETE Function
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[udf_BetaI]
(
@x Float=null
,@a Float=null
,@b Float=null
)
RETURNS Float
AS
BEGIN

Declare @bt Float=0.0
Declare @beta Float=0.0

        if( @x=0 OR @x=1 )
        Begin
            SET @bt = 0
        End
        else if((@x>0) AND (@x<1)) 
            Begin
                SET @bt = (Select dbo.UDF_Gamma(@a+@b)* power(@x,@a)* power(1-@x,@b)/(dbo.UDF_Gamma(@a)*dbo.UDF_Gamma(@b)) )
            End
        if(@x<(@a+1)/(@a+@b+2))
        Begin
            SET @beta = (Select @bt*dbo.udf_betaC(@x,@a,@b)/@a)
        End
        else 
        Begin
            SET @beta = (Select 1-@bt*dbo.udf_betaC(1-@x,@b,@a)/@b)
        End

Return @beta

END

--FDist Function
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[udf_FDist] 
(
@x Float=NULL
,@df1 Float=NULL
,@df2 Float=NULL
)
RETURNS Float
AS
BEGIN
    Declare @x1 Float=(@x*@df1)/((@x*@df1)+@df2)

    return (select 1 - dbo.udf_BetaI(@x1,(@df1/2),(@df2/2)))

END
```

---

Check in Excel =FDIST(0.5,1,1)=0.608173448
and in SQL editor = SELECT udf_FDIST(0.5,1,1)=0.608173457369209

Regards,
Avi

Answer (score 0):

FDIST an FINV Don't exists IN Sql Server.

You can write a SQL Sever function to implement two excel feature.

[Show here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186755.aspx) to create function

Comment: I can create a function for FDIST and FINV. But is there a place or document to understand what are the equation involve in FDIST and FINV. Basically I need to derive this formula out. Any Idea?

Answer (score 0):

in MS SQL Server there is [standard_deviation](http://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms190474%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) 
and some [more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1455370/understanding-t-sql-stdev-stdevp-var-and-varp) statistical functions including variance.

There is also a million workarounds, for example: http://oreilly.com/catalog/transqlcook/chapter/ch08.html

,you need to dig deep into the math for these, though.